# Google Analytics One Page Order Form

Tags: google-analytics

Having looked through the questions already on SO, I can't seem to find the answer on how to track a form that has multiple steps on one page. I saw an example that Google gives but could not really understand the way they were presenting it. What we have is a one page order form and need to track the users that come from a website and end up ordering. the whole ordering process is done with one file so I don't know how to track whether or not someone has actually completed the order. Any help would be great, even directing me to better examples than what Google has shown to me.

Thank you

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the JS function _gaq.push([trackPageview,'/form/stepXX']); each time the process reaches a new step.

You can pass any text string you want as a parameter.
Then you can configure a Goal and a funnel in GA with all the major steps of process

You can also track Events in case of errors for example.

(this uses the GA Async syntax)